# Domain and Range with functions in brackets

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

For the function

$f(x, y) = \sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-2)^2 -1}$

Would it be sufficient to write the domain as

$(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 ≤ 1$

or is that too vague? Then, the range would be $z ≥ 0$ but how could that be expressed in terms of $x$ if the value has to be greater than or equal to $1$?

Comment: I think your inequality is going the wrong way if you want the expression under the square root to be positive.

Comment: If the function is defined amongst reals, your inequality isn't correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is pretty fine, but be careful about the direction of the inequality. If you have $\sqrt{z}$, then you want $z \ge 0$, not $z \le 0$. Since $f : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$, you could write the domain by

$$\mathrm{dom}(f) = \left\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \; \middle| (x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 \ge 1 \right\}$$

as a result. The range of $f$ could simply be given by $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ if you want a symbol for it. You just want the points it is possible for $f$ to map to, regardless of the constraints that need be placed on $x,y$ in order for that to happen.

For instance, you could have $x=y-1$. Then the radicand is given by

$$(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2 - 1 \longrightarrow 2(y-2)^2 - 1$$

Clearly the function $g(y) = \sqrt{2(y-2)^2 - 1}$, for wherever $y$ ensures $g(y)$ is defined, has range $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$.

Comment: True. I did wonder if $(x−1)^2+(y−2)^2≥1$ would be harder to sketch left in that form, but it just creates a circle